# How to get the Structure Jacobian in Dymola?

Tags: modelica, dymola

I notice there is a chapter about "Structure Jacobian" in Dymola Manual 2C, but I am not sure if I could also get the "Structure Jacobian" of my own model in Dymola. I have checked the Dymola manual but didn't find how to do it.

So my question is:

1. Could I get the "Structure Jacobian" of my own model in Dymola?
2. If it is possible, how should I do it?

[image]

Comment: Is "structure Jacobian" the same thing as "incidence matrix"?

Comment: .Yes, they are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct support for getting the incidence structure/structure Jacobian in Dymola 2021 and earlier.

You can some of the incidence structure of the manipulated system from the dependencies ("ModelStructure"-node) in the modelDescription.xml for FMI-export.